# How to modify product page using Theme and Asset api for a shopify App

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template, shopify-liquid

I am creating a Shopify app that will insert a trust seal or badge on the product page. However, there is difficulty in implementing it since there is no clear documentation or tutorials on how to do it. What I want to achieve is to place an image (trust badge) somewhere before or after the Add to cart button. This is a public app, so modifying the theme through Shopify API themes/assets is the only option to do it dynamically.

Shopify is really new to me. I just studied it for 3 weeks, maybe someone who has prior experience in implementing this would help me.

Please refer to the image for reference.
[image]

Thank you in advance! :-)